# google closure: don't strip comments from Java API

Tags: java, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

Is there any way to specify an option **not** to strip comments in the Java API to Google Closure Compiler for JavaScript (especially the google-flavored JavaDoc `/**` comments).

Answer (score 1):

No, someone would have to add it.  It code printer classes don't have any methods for printing comments.